# How do I remove this from the appdelegate and assign it as a button.

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, appdelegate

```
    SLIDERReader *slreader = [[SLIDERReader alloc] init];
    [slreader startRequest];
```

I have these requests in my app delegate 16 of them to be exact.
When I put them in asynchronous blocks, they don't update as fast as I want it.

So what I would like to do is assign this function to a button so that once the user is in the section, they can press that button to start the request and reload the data.

I had a similar question below which resulted in wrapping them in async blocks. 
[How do I move these processes from the AppDelegate and set up individual delegates from each Call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307839/how-do-i-move-these-processes-from-the-appdelegate-and-set-up-individual-delegat)

Comment: When you say they don't update as fast as you'd like, are you switching back to the main thread to to process the results?

Comment: You really need all this methods called in appDelegate methods? My advice is loadData whenever you want. If you make request you should use NSOperationQueue.

Comment: @P-double What I have been noticing is that the application does not does not load them at launch but I have to have the application open for sometime to notice the data being pulled.

Comment: @NevzatR That's exactly what I want to achieve. However I'm not sure how to achieve this. I have everything bundled into a function called "- (void) startRequest" So now all I want to achieve is to assign the function to a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code simply and connect it any UIButton:

```
- (IBAction) sliderReaderMakeRequest {
    SLIDERReader *slreader = [[SLIDERReader alloc] init];
    [slreader startRequest];
}
```

or if you want to do this in thread:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

}

- (IBAction) sliderReaderMakeRequest {

   NSInvocationOperation *op = [[ NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                   selector:@selector(makeSliderRequest)
                                                                    object:nil];
    [_operationQueue addOperation:op];

}

- (void) makeSliderRequest {

   SLIDERReader *slreader = [[SLIDERReader alloc] init];
   [slreader startRequest];

   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishMakeSliderRequest) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

}

- (void) finishMakeSliderRequest  {
     //Whatever you want on main thread with data come from request

}
```